# Symfony, some field still blanks after handleRequest

Tags: php, symfony

I'm learning how yo use symfony, and my problem is, when I want to use the handleRequest function, it did not validate my email en message field, but it's good for name field.

Look the code:

Contact.php entity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Contact
{
    /**
    * @Assert\NotBlank
    */
    private $name;

    /**
    * @Assert\NotBlank
    */
    private $email;

    /**
    * @Assert\NotBlank
    */
    private $message;

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function getMessage()
    {
        return $this->message;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->name = $email;
    }

    public function setMessage($message)
    {
        $this->name = $message;
    }
}

?>
```

BlogController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use App\Entity\Article;
use App\Entity\Contact;
use App\Repository\ArticleRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class BlogController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/blog", name="blog")
     */
    public function blog(ArticleRepository $repo)
    {

        $articles = $repo->findAll();

        return $this->render('blog/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'BlogController',
            'articles' => $articles
        ]);
    }

    /**
    *   @Route("/", name="blog_home")
    */
    public function home()
    {
        return $this->render('blog/home.html.twig');
    }

    /**
    *   @Route("/blog/articles/{id}", name="blog_show")
    */
    public function show(Article $article)
    {
        return $this->render('blog/show.html.twig',[
            'article' => $article
            ]);
    }

    /**
    *   @Route("/contact", name="blog_contact")
    */
    public function contact(Request $request)
    {
        $contact = new Contact; /* Create the new contact object */

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($contact) /* Creating the form */
            ->add('name', TextType::class)
            ->add('email', TextType::class)
            ->add('message', TextareaType::class)
            ->getForm();
            dump($contact);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        dump($contact);
        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
        {

            return $this->redirectToRoute('blog_home');
        }
        dump($request);
        return $this->render('blog/contact.html.twig',[
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
}
```

contact.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}BLOG - Contact{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<h2>Me contacter !</h1>
<div class="row"> 
   <div class="col-md-5">
      {{ form_start(form) }}
         <label>Nom:</label>
         {{ form_widget(form.name) }}
         <label>Email:</label>
         {{ form_widget(form.email) }}
         <label>Message:</label>
         {{ form_widget(form.message) }}
         <br>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Envoie</button>
      {{ form_end(form) }}
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-1">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="card border-info mb-1" style="max-width: 20rem;">
         <div class="card-header">Twitter: @Fergvae</div>
         </div>
      <div class="card border-dark mb-1" style="max-width: 20rem;">
         <div class="card-header">Discord: Fergvae#0730</div>
         </div>
      <div class="card border-danger mb-1" style="max-width: 20rem;">
         <div class="card-header">Youtube: Fergvae</div>
         </div>
   </div>
 </div>
{% endblock %}
```

The only things that didn't work is the handleRequest it's why I made multiple dump.

you also can look the dumped content, the first is before handle and second after.
[Dumped symfony content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUSvG.png)

Thanks to all people who answer this question !

Comment: Have you enter an email and a message in your form ?  Why did you nothing in your form->isSubmitted() closure ? Have you got an error message ? It's not clear

Comment: Yeah I entered an email and a message, I actually do nothing because I deleted what I do before, there were a few lines but nothing important for now, Yeah symfony returned that my email and message field are blank.

Comment: but if I dump the request variable, my request contain what I put in email and message, but not the contact variable after the handlerRequest

Answer (score 0):

Ok my bad, I just forget when I copy past to change the ^this->name in de setters ! Excuse me for the disturb

Answer (score 0):

It's great that you have found your solution, but just in case:

If usage for classes, a better practice is to use a FormType, in there you can declare your class on which fields the form should be automatically created. Which Symfony will automatically catch all of the needed fields and will create the form for you, less code written and etc. Or you can create a custom form, and define all of your needed fields, including restrictions as not empty and etc..

To sum it up, if possible keep as less logic in the controllers as possible and move them deeper.

Comment: Yeah I saw that and it's what I made, thanks for the help !